# Report keeps asking for parameters in an endless loop

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

My CrystalReportViewer that calls a stored procedure. Other reports withnothing other than views work fine using the same code behind. But when I load the report I get an endless loop asking for the parameter and login credentials over and over, claiming "The report you requested requires further information."

```
//Load Config Values
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument crystalReport = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads") + "/CrystalReports/" + dt.Rows[0]["FileName"]);
crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon(DB_UserName, DB_Password, DB_Server, DB_Database);

foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in crystalReport.Database.Tables)
{
    crtablelogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
    crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crconnectioninfo; //Set from earlier configs
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo); //Set from earlier configs
}

crystalReport.Refresh();
crvReport.ReportSource = crystalReport;
```

When I requested additional information for the login, I can only modify the username and password fields. The server field is already pre-populated. Do the Report and stored procedure need to be set up a specific way for this to work?

Comment: why are you splitting this line in regards to concatenation ? `crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads") + "/CrystalReports/" + dt.Rows[0]["FileName"]);` look up how to use `Server.MapPath.Combine` also when you use the debugger what is the value of `dt.Rows[0]["FileName"]` are you getting any casting errors..?

Comment: The value is the name of the report in a guid format: "0e6576bf-5974-4659-b6cf-8a99205a90c3.rpt". No Casting errors or exceptions.

Comment: wonder why your are using a guid as a name of a report.. rather strange.. however.. use the debugger and pinpoint where the issue is happening

Comment: The problem isn't happening in the code behind that I can see. When running this on the test site, it keeps prompting the user to enter the Parameter value, then the login credentials. Once these are entered, it prompts the user again and again. It never actually loads the report from this moment.

Comment: where in the code does this happen.. it's obvious that there is a network credentials issue and or rights issue in regards to the folder where the report resides does the application have permissions to the `Uploads/CrystalReports` folder...?

Comment: yes, the application has full access to this folder. I too am thinking it may be a network credential issue though. Unfortunately, I am unable to see the problem and environment firsthand but I will look into the network issue.

Comment: When you add stored procedure to the rpt file, it will prompt you for parameters, at this point instead of setting null values, use dummy values. This will eventually be overwritten when you run the report. As a matter of interest, is the number of prompts equal to the number of parameters on stored procedure?

Comment: I was finally able to get the report to run as expected locally for debugging purposes. I added CrTable.Location = CrTable.Location in the foreach loop and made sure all the parameters and DB connections mapped up between the report, webconfig, and DB. Now it's working. Thanks for all the help.